NordVPN on Snap Store of Ubuntu is legitimate?
but is the version of NordVPN available on the Ubuntu Snap Store (here's the link:) legitimate?
Running it doesn't do anything...
I reinstalled NordVPN from the terminal and now it works, but I wonder if I might have come across a harmful app before.
Thank you in advance!

Please check if it is a verified app

On June 11, 2024, NordVPN published a blog article mentioning that their VPN client in now available on Snapcraft app store: https://nordvpn.com/blog/nordvpn-now-on-snapcraft-store/
The article mentions https://snapcraft.io/nordvpn as the exact URL. If you installed that package, from Snap Store or with sudo snap install nordvpn, then you've got a legitimate package.

Yes. You can validate it on the upstream source
https://github.com/NordSecurity/nordvpn-linux/blob/main/snap/snapcraft.yaml
mentions
name: nordvpn
title: NordVPN
base: core22

So you can trust this and install it like @Flow menioned
sudo snap install nordvpn

Addtionally - Snap Store request thread for the publisher to be verified - https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/i-d-like-to-be-a-verified-publisher/39430
